# How to access the properties of an object inside an array with help from the index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of events that are presented in a calendar component on my website. When I press a button I should be able to open a modal where the properties of that specific object (in this case event) are shown. How can I access these properties from the index?

```
function openDetails(index) {
   console.log(index)
}

<RevoCalendar
   events={eventList}
   className="calendar"
   style={{
     borderRadius: "5px",
     border: "5px solid #4F6995",
      width: "95%",
   }}
   highlightToday={true}
   languages={translations}
   lang="norwegian"
   primaryColor="#203746"
   secondaryColor="#D7E6EE"
   todayColor="#3B3966"
   textColor="#333333"
   indicatorColor="orange"
   animationSpeed={300}
   sidebarWidth={180}
   detailWidth={280}
   onePanelAtATime={false}
   openDetailsOnDateSelection={true}
   allowDeleteEvent={true}
   timeFormat24={true}
   showAllDayLabel={false}
   detailDateFormat="dddd, DD. MMMM YYYY"
   sidebarDefault={true}
   detailDefault={true}
   deleteEvent={index => openDetails(index)}
/>
```

Comment: Why not change the openDetails signature to take the event instead of the index?
i.e. `index => openDetails(events[index])`

Comment: When I try to log ```eventList[index]```, I get undefined. Don't know if this was what you meant with your answer.

Comment: Never mind, found the answer. I have overseen what index includes when it gets passed to openDetails. Index contained the whole event when the button was clicked.